# Unresolved reference: inflate, Android studio veiwBinding error

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I was trying to implement `viewBinding` in Kotlin android studio project but it pops up an error like this: `Unresolved reference: inflate` I tried all the suggestions given on this site and the actions suggested by android studio (to import various things), but I was still not able to resolve it. My code is as follows:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View.inflate
import androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.inflate
import androidx.core.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat.inflate


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding=ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    }
}
```

I have already implemented veiwbinding in buid gradle:

```
 android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    ...
}
```

Can anyone please tell me:

1. what's the solution to this problem?
2. what exactly is causing this problem?

Comment: hmm.. that sounds strange. Does it give any autocomplete options when you just type a dot behind `ActivityMainBinding`? Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMyMc.png

Comment: No sir even I was surprised at that.

Comment: Maybe somehow you imported the wrong `ActivityMainBinding`. Should be something like `import yourpackagename.databinding.ActivityMainBinding`

Comment: could you please suggest me some solution to this problem.

Comment: could you please elaborate

Comment: What does your import statement look like for the `ActivityMainBinding`?

Comment: Sir I have implemented your suggestion in the `MainActivity.kt` file and the error is gone but I wanted to ask that I have only enabled `viewBinding` in `build gradle` . But you have suggested me to import some `databinding` kind of file, so would it create any problems in future while writing the code in the file?? Also should I just enable `databinding` too in `build gradle` to prevent any future errors??

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean. Writing `viewBinding true` in gradle is the reason why you are even able to import the binding. This is how it works

Comment: no sir I wanted to ask that I have just enabled `viewBinding` only then importing a `.dataBinding.ActivityMainBinding` file which you suggested wouldn't create any problems in the future right while righting the code in the file??

Comment: @Ankit when you use *view binding*, the library takes your XML file (`activity_main.xml`) and *generates* a class called `ActivityMainBinding`, which has variables for all the views in your layout that have an ID. You have to import that class to be able to use it, which is why you need an import line pointing to that class. `.databinding.ActivityMainBinding` is just where it's generated, in a package called `databinding`. Usually the import happens automatically, and that's the line it adds!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a button in your xml and call it in the activity file by setOnClickListener. This is to check if the layout is inflating without any issue. **NOTE**: add setContentView(binding.root) like I did in the onCreate

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding=ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        // Add this line
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // continueBtn --> the nameof the button id the xml
        binding.continueBtn.setOnClickListener {
            println("HELLO THERE")
        }

    }
```